# Copy m3u8 segment files on a single mp4 format

Tags: c#, asp.net, ffmpeg

Hi I used below command for copy m3u8 segment files to a single mp4 file:

I run this command on c# `Process` class.

```
    -y -i "D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\1\m3u8\200p\out.m3u8"  
    -y -i "D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\1\m3u8\360p\out.m3u8"  
    -y -i "D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\1\m3u8\480p\out.m3u8"  
    -y -i "D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\1\m3u8\720p\out.m3u8" 
-map 0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -threads 0 "D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\1\1-200.mp4" 
-map 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -threads 0 "D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\1\1-360.mp4" 
-map 2 -c:v copy -c:a copy -threads 0 "D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\1\1-480.mp4" 
-map 3 -c:v copy -c:a copy -threads 0 "D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\1\1.mp4"
```

I get this Error:

```
[hls,applehttp @ 00000000047e3400] Failed to open segment of playlist 0
    Last message repeated 353 times
[hls,applehttp @ 00000000047e3400] Error when loading first segment 'out0.ts'
D:\OtherProjects\ConvertProj\video\2018\4\6208-3905956\m3u8\200p\out.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

What is the problem? Waht I must be do? Is this a bug?

Comment: It is a bug. If your segments are not using any paths in the m3u8 manifest which is pretty common, FFmpeg then does not construct proper paths to access the segments as local files and expects them in the same folder where the executable is.

If you're pressed for time, your option to work around this is to change the segment paths in m3u8 to absolute, or put ffmpeg to the folder where the segments are and then call the associated m3u8 manifest from there.

Or alternatively, if you have the means to access the m3u8 manifests from ffmpeg via http, do that. That should work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the addressing of inputs and outputs in this way on below new command as the path of ffmpeg:

```
-y -i "../video/2018/4/1/m3u8/200p/out.m3u8"  
-y -i "../video/2018/4/1/m3u8/360p/out.m3u8"  
-y -i "../video/2018/4/1/m3u8/480p/out.m3u8"  
-y -i "../video/2018/4/1/m3u8/720p/out.m3u8" 
-map 0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -threads 0 "../video/2018/4/1/1-200.mp4" 
-map 1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -threads 0 "../video/2018/4/1/1-360.mp4" 
-map 2 -c:v copy -c:a copy -threads 0 "../video/2018/4/1/1-480.mp4" 
-map 3 -c:v copy -c:a copy -threads 0 "../video/2018/4/1/1.mp4"
```

and I set the `/video/` path for `WorkingDirectory` of c# process class which ffmpeg doesn't exist on that.